# How can I include a pic figure as external file in groff?

Tags: groff, postscript, roff

While using `groff` and `pic` it is possible to do:

```
$ cat test.ms
.TL
Test

.NH 1 
Test Header

.PS
circle
arrow
box
.PE
$ cat test.ms | groff -ms -p > test.ps
```

Which generates a valid `test.ps` file containing the processed figure in `pic`.

In larger documents, for mainteinability, it might be desirable to keep the picture `pic` description in a separate file and invoke such file from the main `.ms` file.

While trying to get this working I have found that `.so` can source an external file, but I am finding issues to set up this configuration of embeding  external `.pic` files into the main `.ms` file as shown here:

```
$ cat test2.pic
.PS
circle
arrow
box
.PE
$ cat test2.ms
.TL
Test

.NH 1 
Test Header

.so test2.pic
$ cat test2.ms | groff -ms -p > test2.ps
test2.pic:1: macro error: bad arguments to PS (not preprocessed with pic?)
$
```

Which would be the way to achieve this inclusion of `.pic` code in the main macro `.ms` files as external files?

Comment: What does `s`, the parameter to `-m` have? Your commands return: `troff: fatal error: can't find macro file s
`

Comment: `-ms` tells `groff` to use `ms` macro package. Notice that I am using `groff`. It might be that `troff` has a different syntax for using `ms` macros. I have noticed that `troff` can not invoke other arguments such as `-p` (preprocess with pic)

Comment: Note, you can also include pic files by giving the filename to the PS macro, eg `.PS <test2.pic` where it acts a bit like `.so`.

Comment: I did not know that. Maybe it makes even more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `soelim` preprocessor, that will eliminate the `.so` commands by including the actual files.

In your case this should it (note the added `-s` flag):

```
cat test2.ms | groff -ms -p -s > test2.ps
```